# Aligning array elements horizontally LaTeX

Tags: arrays

I'm trying to build a graphic illustration of how a binary multiplication is solved, but I'm facing some problems while trying to align the cells of the array.
Here's the code:

```
\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
    &&1&1&0 & * \\
    &&&1&1 & = \\
\end{array}\newline
\rule{0.25\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\
\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
    &&1&1&0 &  \\
    &1&1&0&- &  \\
\end{array}\newline
\rule{0.25\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\
\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
    1&0&0&1&0_2 \\
\end{array}\newline
```

And here's the result:
[image]

Comment: Try using a single array.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use only one `{array}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{@{}cccccc@{}}
  &   & 1 & 1 & 0  & * \\
  &   &   & 1 & 1  & = \\ \hline
  &   & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  & 1 & 1 & 0 & \text{--} \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0_2 \\
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: That's nice! Is there any way to align the 0_2 to the right so that the 0 is aligned with the other numbers as well?

Comment: @Shark44 - You could replace `0_2` with `0\rlap{$_2$}`. Alternatively, you could load the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools) package (a superset of the `amsmath` package) and replace `0_2` with `0\mathrlap{_2}`.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly